# View for Team List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a bit of a 'what is it' question.

Currently, I am trying to create a page that will create teams, and allow the user to select the member for those teams.

So far, dynamically render ListBoxes (amount based on teams selected) to the page, then the user selects a member, and adds them to the team.

I want to allow for an **x** amount of teams added, but this will get messy with the amount of list boxers that could *possibly* be added.

I would like to know if there is a view that could represent that in once clean environment. I would like do display the team name, in the header, and its member beneath - with editing options on them. I've looked up the GridView and ListView, but I cant see how they could do *exactly as i wanted.* I have provided a highly refined picture to help elaborate.

[image: Very well crafted picture]

**Edit:** This is not a 'how do I do this - gimmie code question. I would just like to know IF it could be done, and if so, what control I could use. Mayb even a reference to a page with something similar to give me a quick tutorial ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at the `Repeater` web forms control. You can nest them.

Comment: I had a look at the `Repeater`.. I currently only use them to databind items from a Database - quite effectively at that. But I have no idea how it could help me in this >.< - looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571363/nested-repeaters-in-asp-net