# Repeater grouping items from single database

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I have a table with headers(example):  Group, DisplayName, EditableData, description.
I have been trying for the last few days to learn repeaters to sort the information based on the Group so I can get something that looks like the following layout.  This is a user control I am trying to put together.

```
Group1
------------------
Name1     EditableData    Some Description
Name2     EditableData    Some Description

Group2
------------------
Name3     EditableData    Some Description
Name4     EditableData    Some Description
```

I have looked a the following other examples online:
[Nested repeaters - grouping data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13196686/nested-repeaters-grouping-data) and
[Nested Repeaters in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571363/nested-repeaters-in-asp-net)

I believe I do not properly understand how repeaters work enough to deal with nesting or datasource.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        Group: <%#Eval("Group")%><br />
        <%--Nested Repeater would go here for all the children info for each "Group"--%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Using DISTINCT in my SQL to just retrieve "Group" leaves me with the proper groups without repeats and I guess I could just instead set the groups in labels and then later make repeaters for each specific label...  This seems terrible when I may later update editableData back to the database.

What I really want I guess is at least a link to a walkthrough that explains how repeaters work along with Eval() and datasources.  I mean, code to do everything I need to complete this first step in my project would be perfect ;P  But I also want to be able to understand these better as I am probably going to be using them often in the near future.

Comment: I suggest you use a listview or grid view. No repeaters required. For the heading, just add that row to the grid as a separate row, and then on the item data bind event, just hide or show the one extra row as a grouping heading.

Comment: I wound up using a Telerik RadGrid for this.  GroupByExpressions and GroupByFields made it all go quickly.  Jamshaid's answer helped the most based on repeaters and Albert's post on listview was something I had never even considered... and seems really easy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once encountered the same issue where I was to sort the data by group and I had to display the common items in a grouped segment.

There are of-course multiple ways of how you retrieve data, for example, you can get Distinct Group Names and bind it to the repeater and then on `ItemDataBound` event you can execute and get other elements like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrGroups" OnItemDataBound="rptrGroups_ItemDataBound">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGroupName" Text='<%# Eval("GroupName") %>' />

        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv">
        </asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>

protected void rptrGroups_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
    {
        var lblGroupName = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("lblGroupName");
        GridView gv = (GridView)e.Item.FindControl("table");

        var dataTable = FetchDataWithGroupName(lblGroupName.Text); // Method that fetches data with groupname.
        gv.DataSource = dataTable;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

This is not a recommended way because it goes to database, runs query, and then fetches data for each item (if you are fetching this data from db). If you have thousands of Groups then it will make db calls for thousands of times which is a bad thing.

The second solution is, you design a model and feed a custom model that will do the job. Let me explain it by a sample model:

```
public class GroupedModel
{
    public string GroupName {get; set;}
    public List<NestedData> TableData {get; set;}
}
public class NestedData
{
    public string Id {get; set;}
    // Your columns here...
}
```

Then query and initialize list of `GroupedModel` class then feed it to the `repeater`. Let me do it with some dummy data.

```
var tableData = new List<NestedData>();
var nestedData1 = new NestedData { Id = "1" };
var nestedData2 = new NestedData { Id = "2" };

tableData.Add(nestedData1);
tableData.Add(nestedData2);

var groupedModel = new GroupedModel 
{
    GroupName = "Group1",
    TableData = tableData
};

var listGroupedModel = new List<GroupedModel>();
listGroupedModel.Add(groupedModel);

rptrGroups.DataSource = listGroupedModel;
```

Then modify the markup like this:

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="rptrGroups">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblGroupName" Text='<%# Eval("GroupName") %>' />

        <asp:GridView runat="server" ID="gv" DataSource='<%# ((GroupedModel)Container.DataItem).TableData %>'>
        </asp:GridView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 2):

I find that just using a gridview or list view works rather nice. However, DO NOT attempt to use the grouping feature - as it is for placing items across the page, not down.

Lets make this really simple!

Ok, so I have a list of Hotels, but I want to group by city.

So, you build a query like this:

```
    Dim strSQL As String = 
       "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, HotelName, City FROM tblHotels ORDER BY City, HotelName"

    GridView1.DataSource = Myrst(strSQL)
    GridView1.DataBind()
```

Ok, so that fills out our grid view. We get this:

[image]

So far, two lines of code!

But, we want to group by City.

So at the forms class level, add simple var:

```
Public Class HotelGroupGrid
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim LastCity As String    <----- this one

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        If IsPostBack = False Then
            LastCity = ""
            Call LoadGrid()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Ok, so now on the data item bind event, simply add a NEW row.

The code looks like this:

```
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        ' if grouping = 1 then create a new row!
        Dim gvRow As DataRowView = DirectCast(e.Row.DataItem, DataRowView)

        If gvRow("City") <> LastCity Then
            LastCity = gvRow("City")

            ' insert a new row for grouping header
            Dim MyRow As New GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal)
            Dim MyCel As New TableCell()
            'MyCel.Width = Unit.Percentage(100)
            Dim MyTable As Table = e.Row.Parent

            MyCel.ColumnSpan = MyTable.Rows(0).Controls.Count
            Dim MyLable As New Label
            MyLable.Text = "<h2>" & gvRow("City") & "</h2>"
            MyCel.Controls.Add(MyLable)
            MyRow.Cells.Add(MyCel)
            MyTable.Rows.AddAt(MyTable.Rows.Count - 1, MyRow)

        End If

    End If
```

Now, above is a "bit" of a chunk to chew on - but still not a lot of code.

So, now when we run above, we get this:

[image]

Our grid view markup looks like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID">
  <Columns>
    <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" SortExpression="FirstName" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" SortExpression="LastName" />
     <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" SortExpression="HotelName" />
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

So, not too bad.

If you decide to use a listview? Then the code becomes quite a bit less, but the markup for listview is quite a handfull.

All we do is create a row that is our heading, and now show, or hide that row based on the start of new grouping.

So, if one decides to use a list view? Then we get this:

(I assume you use the databind wizards - your not possibly typing in the markup by hand - right? - saving world poverty here)

So, for a list view (and I think the list view is BETTER, since the layout options for that heading row is wide open to any kind markup and extra controls you dream up.

So, the markup (generated - and then chopped out the fat) is this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID">
    <EmptyDataTemplate>
        <table runat="server" style="">
           <tr><td>No data was returned.</td></tr>
        </table>
    </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>

       <tr id="GroupHeading" runat="server" style="display:none">
           <td colspan="4">
           <h2><asp:Label ID="City" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("City") %>' /></h2>
           </td>
       </tr>

       <tr>
          <td><asp:Label ID="IDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' /></td>
          <td><asp:Label ID="FirstNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FirstName") %>' /></td>
          <td><asp:Label ID="LastNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("LastName") %>' /></td>
          <td><asp:Label ID="HotelNameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("HotelName") %>' /></td>
       </tr>
   </ItemTemplate>

 <LayoutTemplate>
     <table id="itemPlaceholderContainer" runat="server" border="0" style="">
     <tr runat="server">
        <th runat="server">ID</th>
        <th runat="server">FirstName</th>
        <th runat="server">LastName</th>
        <th runat="server">HotelName</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server">
    </tr>

    </table>
 </LayoutTemplate>
 </asp:ListView>
```

Now no question that the listview spits out a lot more markup - but we now have a full row for the heading. So we get this:

[image]

But, now our code simply will hide or show that "extra" row we have in the marketup.

And it quite simple now:

```
If e.Item.GetType = GetType(ListViewDataItem) Then

  Dim MyRow As HtmlTableRow = e.Item.FindControl("GroupHeading")
  Dim lblCity As Label = MyRow.FindControl("City")
  If lblCity.Text <> LastCity Then
     LastCity = lblCity.Text
     ' Hide/show  group heading
     MyRow.Style("display") = "normal"
  Else
     MyRow.Style("display") = "none"
  End If

End If
```

So the trick in most cases is to simply layout that extra row item, and then on the item data bound event you simply hide or show that heading part.