# Nested Repeater in Asp.Net for beginners

Tags: c#, asp.net

I use repeater in asp.net to show data in web page, now i want to show data in tree from like in "main category -> sub category" etc...

I have two table Comment and replay_comments.  I am able to show comments successfully, but not able to show replies on those comments.

**Asp.Net code**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Detail.aspx.cs" Inherits="Detail" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style>
        body
        {
           padding:0;
           margin:0;
            background-color:whitesmoke;
        }
        .main
        {
            border:1px solid black;
            background-color:silver;
            width:40%;
            height:auto;
            background-repeat:repeat-y;
            padding:0;
            margin:0;

        }
        .question
        {


            text-align:left;
        }
        .question .ques
        {
            padding-left:20px;

        }
        .question .ans{
            padding-left:20px;

        }
        .comment{

        }
        panel
        {
            margin-bottom:20px;
        }
        table
        {

            width:50%;

        }
        td
        {
            border-bottom:1px solid white;
            margin-bottom:10px;
        }
        .rep
        {
            top:-20px;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="position:relative; text-align:center;">
        <div class="main">
        <div class="question">
        <asp:Label ID="Question" ForeColor="Red" runat="server" Text="Question"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<asp:Label CssClass="ques" ID="Ques" runat="server" Height="20px" Width="400px"></asp:Label><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Answer" ForeColor="Green" runat="server" Text="Answer"></asp:Label>&nbsp; <asp:Label ID="Ans" CssClass="ans" runat="server" Text="" Height="60px" Width="400px"></asp:Label>
        </div>
        <div class="comment">

            <table>


         <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" Height="140px" Width="378px">
            <asp:Repeater ID="repUserComments" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repUserComments_ItemCommand" OnItemDataBound="repUserComments_ItemDataBound">
                <ItemTemplate>
                   <tr>
                       <td>
                     <p>
                        <%#Eval("Username") %>
                        Commented on
                        <%#Eval("Date_Created") %>
                    </p>

                    <div><%#Eval("Comment") %></div>  


        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="replay" runat="server" CssClass="rep" OnClick="replay_Click" Text="Replay"/>

        </p>

 </td>

                       </tr>

                    <tr>
                         <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="repuser" Visible="false" runat="server">Username</asp:Label>&nbsp; <br />
                             <asp:TextBox ID="uname" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox><br />
                        <asp:Label ID="repcoment" Visible="false" runat="server">Replay</asp:Label>&nbsp; <br />
                             <asp:TextBox ID="comreplay" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox><br />
                        <asp:Button ID="savereplay" runat="server" Text="Replay Post" Visible="false" OnClick="savereplay_Click"/>
                    </td>
                    </tr>
                   <asp:Repeater ID="replay_comments" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="replay_comments_ItemDataBound">
                       <ItemTemplate>
                       <p>
                        <%#Eval("username") %>
                        Commented on
                        <%#Eval("date") %>
                    </p>

                    <div><%#Eval("replay") %></div>  
                           </ItemTemplate>  
                   </asp:Repeater>

                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </asp:Panel>
                </table>
            </div>


        <div style="text-align:left; margin-left:40px;">
        <asp:Label ID="User" runat="server" Text="User"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 14px"></asp:TextBox>
        <p>
            <asp:Label ID="coment" runat="server" Text="Comment"></asp:Label>&nbsp;<br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="Comment" runat="server" Height="85px" Width="147px" MaxLength="500" Rows="10"></asp:TextBox>
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Post Comment" />
        </p>
       </div>

            </div>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

**Code Behind**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class Detail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=MSZ900; integrated security=true; initial catalog=Test");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) //----- Make sure you always bind your databound controls after this.
        {
            con.Open();
            string st = Request.QueryString["id"];
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from faq where ID='" + st + "'", con);
            SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select * from comment where Qid='" + st + "'", con);

            cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader drr;
            SqlDataReader dr;


            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {


                Ques.Text = dr["Question"].ToString();
                Ans.Text = dr["Answer"].ToString();
            }
            dr.Close();
            drr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
            //---- bind comments
            if (drr.HasRows)
            {

                repUserComments.DataSource=drr;

                repUserComments.DataBind();


            }
            drr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        string st = Request.QueryString["id"];
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string qry = "insert into comment(ID,Username,Comment,Date_Created,Qid)values('" + st + "','" + username.Text + "','" + Comment.Text + "','" + dt + "','" + st + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        username.Text = string.Empty;
        Comment.Text = string.Empty;
        Response.Redirect("detail.aspx?id=" + st);

        con.Close();
    }
    protected void repUserComments_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.CommandName=="preplay")
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                con.Open();

               TextBox username = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("cusername");
                TextBox replay = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("commentreplay");
                string st = Request.QueryString["id"];
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                string qry = "insert into comment_replay(username,replay,date)values('" + username.Text + "','" + replay.Text + "','" + dt + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                username.Text = string.Empty;
                replay.Text = string.Empty;

                con.Close();

            }
        }



    }
    protected void replay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        RepeaterItem rpt = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
        Label repu = (Label)rpt.FindControl("repuser");
        TextBox user =(TextBox)rpt.FindControl("uname");
        Label repcomment = (Label)rpt.FindControl("repcoment");
        TextBox cmnt = (TextBox)rpt.FindControl("comreplay");
        Button save = (Button)rpt.FindControl("savereplay");
        user.Visible = true;
        cmnt.Visible = true;
        save.Visible = true;
        repu.Visible = true;
        repcomment.Visible = true;

    }
    protected void savereplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        string st = Request.QueryString["id"];
        Button sv = (Button)sender;
        RepeaterItem rptt = (RepeaterItem)sv.NamingContainer;
        TextBox user = (TextBox)rptt.FindControl("uname");
        TextBox cmnt = (TextBox)rptt.FindControl("comreplay");
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string qry = "insert into comment_replay(username,replay,date,Qid)values('" + user.Text + "','" + cmnt.Text + "','" + dt + "','"+st+"')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();


    }

    protected void replay_comments_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void repUserComments_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        string st = Request.QueryString["id"];
        RepeaterItem item = e.Item;
        if ((item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) ||
            (item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
          Repeater replay = (Repeater)item.FindControl("replay_comments");

          replay.DataSource = ((DataRowView)item.DataItem).CreateChildView("repUserComments");
            replay.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

i am able to use nested repeater, but know the problem is that if i replay on comment 1, then the replay will also show under comment2, comment 3 and so on, but i want that it will show only under the specified comment (comment 1).

My updated code is....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;


public partial class Detail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("data source=MSZ900; integrated security=true; initial catalog=Test; MultipleActiveResultSets=true");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack) //----- Make sure you always bind your databound controls after this.
        {
            con.Open();
            string st = Request.QueryString["id"];
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from faq where Qid='" + st + "'", con);
            SqlCommand cmdd = new SqlCommand("select * from comment where Qid='" + st + "'", con);

            cmdd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            SqlDataReader drr;
            SqlDataReader dr;


            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (dr.Read())
            {


                Ques.Text = dr["Question"].ToString();
                Ans.Text = dr["Answer"].ToString();
            }
            dr.Close();
            drr = cmdd.ExecuteReader();
            //---- bind comments
            if (drr.HasRows)
            {

                repUserComments.DataSource=drr;

                repUserComments.DataBind();


            }
            drr.Close();
            con.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        string st = Request.QueryString["id"];
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string qry = "insert into comment(Username,Comment,Date_Created,Qid)values('" + username.Text + "','" + Comment.Text + "','" + dt + "','" + st + "')";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        username.Text = string.Empty;
        Comment.Text = string.Empty;
        Response.Redirect("detail.aspx?id=" + st);

        con.Close();
    }
    protected void repUserComments_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.CommandName=="preplay")
        {
            if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
            {
                con.Open();

               TextBox username = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("cusername");
                TextBox replay = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("commentreplay");
                string st = Request.QueryString["id"];
                DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
                string qry = "insert into comment_replay(username,replay,date)values('" + username.Text + "','" + replay.Text + "','" + dt + "')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


                username.Text = string.Empty;
                replay.Text = string.Empty;

                con.Close();

            }
        }



    }
    protected void replay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        RepeaterItem rpt = (RepeaterItem)btn.NamingContainer;
        Label repu = (Label)rpt.FindControl("repuser");
        TextBox user =(TextBox)rpt.FindControl("uname");
        Label repcomment = (Label)rpt.FindControl("repcoment");
        TextBox cmnt = (TextBox)rpt.FindControl("comreplay");
        Button save = (Button)rpt.FindControl("savereplay");
        user.Visible = true;
        cmnt.Visible = true;
        save.Visible = true;
        repu.Visible = true;
        repcomment.Visible = true;

    }
    protected void savereplay_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        string st = Request.QueryString["id"];
        Button sv = (Button)sender;
        RepeaterItem rptt = (RepeaterItem)sv.NamingContainer;
        TextBox user = (TextBox)rptt.FindControl("uname");
        TextBox cmnt = (TextBox)rptt.FindControl("comreplay");
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        string qry = "insert into comment_replay(username,replay,date,Commentid)values('" + user.Text + "','" + cmnt.Text + "','" + dt + "','"+st+"')";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, con);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();


    }

    protected void replay_comments_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
    }

    protected void repUserComments_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)



    {
      if(e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.Item||e.Item.ItemType==ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
      {

          Repeater rept = e.Item.FindControl("replay_comments") as Repeater;
          string id = Request.QueryString["id"].ToString();
          //string id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Commentid").ToString();
          SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select username,date,replay from comment_replay where Commentid='" +id+ "'", con);

          DataTable dt = new DataTable();

          SqlDataAdapter dap = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
          dap.Fill(dt);
          rept.DataSource = dt;
          rept.DataBind();
      }



    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using the following method? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571363/nested-repeaters-in-asp-net

Comment: please read my update....

Comment: In your savereplay_Click function does request.QueryString["id"] return the id of the comment or the id of the user?

Comment: it is the comment id.

Comment: check http://aspalliance.com/732_display_hierarchical_data_with_treeview_in_aspnet_20

Answer (score 0):

When you click on 'Replay' button, `replay_Click()` is simply showing the elements that are hidden.

When you click on 'Replay Post', `savereplay_Click()` submits your form to itself and, since `Request.QueryString["id"]` is the question id passed on the url, you always save your replays with the wrong id.

When `repUserComments_ItemDataBound` you, once again, calls `Request.QUeryString["id"]` which, again, is the question id from the url. That's why all your comments have the same replays.

You need to structure better your code and pass the correct id's on the respective get/post methods, otherwise you will always save wrong information on your database.

**EDIT**

Like said in comments, to include a hidden field you use (don't know your database schema, so Eval to correct field if needed):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="CmntId" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("CommentId") %>' />
<asp:Label ID="repuser" Visible="false" runat="server">Username</asp:Label>&nbsp; <br />
<asp:TextBox ID="uname" runat="server" Visible="false"></asp:TextBox><br />
```

Then on your `savereplay_Click()`:

```
HiddenField hiddenField = (HiddenField)rptt.FindControl("CmntId");
string st = hiddenField.Value;
```

Comment: Sir i also tried 'string id = DataBinder.Eval(e.Item.DataItem, "Commentid").ToString();' but it result the same..

Comment: @webydesigny - On your repeaters you could always have a hidden input and bind the respectives id's on it. That way you can simply FindControl and get the value. I believe that you need this specially in `savereplay_Click()` as this one is the guy saving your data for replays.